# Export Webpage Table to an excel file

Tags: html, excel, export

I need to pass the table Série B in the figure to an excel, I tried in excel by "Get Data / From Web" but is not giving any result, I think it´s not passing because the code of the page is DIV, there is an alternative option to pass to excel?

[Table "Serie B" from webpage that I want to export to an excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKSCT.png)

Thanks

I want to export table "serie B" to excel and every time I open the excel file will be refresh.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.